# Add a HOOK to mysql results (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, hook

I have a script that outputs a username in about 100 files. I now want to use a class to generate the username from the userid.

Is there a way to add a hook to this to do it, or do I have to manually edit all the files?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your script provides a hook, there is probably no way to change this without altering the files.

You could theoretically capture the script output using output buffering, and do a search+replace in the data, but that is terrible practice.

To avoid the same problem in the future, instead of changing each occurrence to a different value, you could insert a call to a `showName()`  function or method that you define in a central file.

Comment: This is my idea. I would have say Names.class.php, which would take the userid, and return the proper username

Comment: @Insanity yeah, that sounds sensible.

Comment: an advanced (and I mean *advanced* tactic) for consideration would be using anon functions, new in php 5.3.  There's also the observer design pattern, in which you use an event dispatcher, event objects, and listeners to interpret and modify the data; this method provides a lot more functionality than simply hooking.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: there's this to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern - an implementation of this pattern in PHP is here: http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/ - myself and a few others took the idea of how the symfony event dispatcher worked and then made our own, which is available here: https://github.com/OpenFlame/OpenFlame-Framework/tree/develop-1.1/Event

Comment: the logic behind it, also: basically, the listeners register themselves as references for callbacks to be used inside of the event dispatcher for events of specific names.  in your code, when you want to "hook", you create a new event and then pass it to the event dispatcher to trigger it, which then dispatches that event to the listeners registered to that event's name.  as the event is an object, you can attach and modify data stored within it in order to modify your application's behavior.